# timeout expired error in c#

Tags: c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I got the following error when I tried to execute stored procedure through c#.net

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. at Phn.ClsAdminShowContentDB.getProviderContent(Int32 id, String sortby, String sortas, String search) in d:\AspDotNetProjects2010\PrivateHealthNews\App_Code\DataAccess Layer\ClsAdminShowContentDB.cs:line 61 at Phn.clsAdminShowContent.getProviderContent(Int32 id, String sortby, String sortas, String search) in d:\AspDotNetProjects2010\PrivateHealthNews\App_Code\Business Layer\Logic Layer\clsAdminShowContent.cs:line 33 at Admin_view_content.Showcontent(String orderby, String strVal) in d:\AspDotNetProjects2010\PrivateHealthNews\Admin\view_content.aspx.cs:line 117

can you please tell me how can I solve this

Comment: The stored procedure is taking too long - you need to optimize it. Adding indexes on the queried tables can help, but without details of table structure and the actual query, no more advice can be given.

Comment: If you are using MS SQL Server, you can use [SQL Profiler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091) to profile the executed statements and then optimize them (reduce IO by adding an index, etc - this depends highly on the trace output and your usage / the queryplan etc.).